# How to write multiple lines in a single line?

Tags: python

How can I write multiple lines in a single line? My inputs are like this:

```
HOXC11
HOXC11, HOX3H, MGC4906
human, Homo sapiens


HOXB6
HOXB6, HOX2, HU-2, HOX2B, Hox-2.2
human, Homo sapiens


HOXB13
HOXB13
human, Homo sapiens


PAX5
PAX5, BSAP
human, Homo sapiens
```

I need to make it into a single line like this:

```
HOXC11   HOXC11, HOX3H, MGC4906  human, Homo sapiens
HOXB6    HOXB6, HOX2, HU-2, HOX2B, Hox-2.2    human, Homo sapiens
HOXB13   HOXB13     human, Homo sapiens
```

Comment: Then don't write a newline ("\n"). Note that `print` will *normally* write a newline unless suppressed. Python 2 or 3?

Comment: my inputs are like this

Comment: HOXC11
HOXC11, HOX3H, MGC4906
human, Homo sapiens


HOXB6
HOXB6, HOX2, HU-2, HOX2B, Hox-2.2
human, Homo sapiens


HOXB13
HOXB13
human, Homo sapiens

Comment: Okay.. and? How are they read? Being written? There is a good chance the original newlines are being consumed and new ones are generated..

Comment: Humans don't do any better when confronted with variables referenced before assignment than the interpreter does. Slow down and explain your the input, the process it goes through, and the desired output.

Comment: its like hoxc11 then in second line hoxc11,hox3h,mgc4906 then in third line homo papiens

Comment: And we have no idea what the actual data structure looks like. For all we know, you could have a bunch of `print('\t\t')` statements between each line of output. Repeating the unclear information does not help.

Comment: i am not able to put the proper input don't know why it is giving in single lne

Comment: And we don't know either, because you haven't told us anything about the code or the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input is from a file, let's call it `homosapiens.txt`, you can go from the specified input to the desired output as follow:

```
with open('homosapiens.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line == 'human, Homo sapiens':
            print line  # this will print and go to a newline
        elif line:
            print line,  # the comma after line suppresses the newline
```

Comment: How so? Can you give me the output and the traceback?

Comment: the input will be read1\n read2\n read3\n, in three lines and the output should be like read1 read2 read3 in single line

Comment: what happens when you run the code above? an exception? a wrong output? copy and paste the output on the terminal here, please

Answer (score 0):

```
  textInput = textInput.rstrip('\n')
```

Comment: Note that textInput is the variable storing the input.
Replace it to suit your code.

Comment: This almost certainly won't answer the question, because the question in its current form is unanswerable.

Comment: You mean, you want it to appear in one line... like this code appears in one line?